# What are the drawbacks of using traits in Entities?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have just discovered that I can use Traits to add some behaviors to my Entities.

I'm starting playing with it, and it seems awesome. But I have some questions, before implementing in all my entities.

Basically, what are the drawbacks of using the Traits in the Entities ?

Because as I see the things, I can have a trait to manage each generic field an entity can have (like name, description, id, ...). But this can end up by using many traits in one Entity.

The drawbacks I can figure out for now are :

- We will have a dependency to another bundle which will store all the behaviors we want
- We need to use annotation for the mapping (with yaml, we will need to manually create the mapping for each entity using the Trait), so we can directly annotate field in the Trait (with yaml, we will need to manually create the mapping for each entity using the Trait). But by using annotation, if we want to support Entity and Document, we will have to duplicate some code

And a more generic question : Is there some performances impact of using Trait in PHP (can not find good resource on the web about it) ?

Answer (score 1):

Traits are still a relatively new feature in PHP and not broadly used in libraries and frameworks.

I have not tested it, but I guess that traits will not have an impact on your system performance. Always remember: Almost nothing you write in your application code will impact the performance of your application in any way as long you do not iterate 500k times or fire hundreds of queries at your database (a.k.a. doing something stupid).

Some trait-specific bundles:

- https://github.com/KnpLabs/ControllerBehaviors
- https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors